# Submitting two form with a submit button with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Explanation :

Here's the situation goes . I'm searching a way to call another Ajax function when the data is success but I'm unable to do due to unknown circumstances.

Code:

---HTML Form :

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8"  id="contactForm1" style="margin-top:;" action="" method="post">
    <input class="wf-input wf-req wf-valid__email" type="text" name="email"
         data-placeholder="yes" id="email" value="Enter Your Email Here" onfocus=" 
         if (this.value == 'Enter Your Email Here') 
         { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if (this.value == '') 
         { this.value='Enter Your Email Here';} " style="margin-top:;">
    </input>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="wf-button" name="submit1" value=" " style="display:  inline !important; margin-top:-10px !important;"></input>
</form>
```

----Ajax Code :

```
$(function() {
    $('.wf-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var frm = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {
            email: email
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
            // Need to place it here
            frm.submit();
            } else {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is not valid.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---Another form with HTML in the same page:-

```
    <form method="post" id ="aweber" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="947846900" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="awlist3599001" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.aweber.com/thankyou.htm?m=default" id="redirect_37ecf313df3b6f27b92c34c2c00ef203" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="ibb_test" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
<div id="af-form-947846900" class="af-form"><div id="af-body-947846900"  class="af-body af-standards">
<div class="af-element">
<label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-66127140">Email: </label>
<div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-66127140" type="text" name="email" value=""  />
</div><div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="af-element buttonContainer">
<<input name="submitaw" id="submitaw" class="wf-button" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="501" />
<div class="af-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;"><img src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/displays.htm?id=nCzsHCxsnAwM" alt="" /></div>
</form>
```

Scenarion :

I would when the Ajax trigger when the user click the submit button for the ID ContactForm1. 
Before submitting the form , I want the Ajax to send the same value to the other form in the same page and click submit .

How?

Comment: are you saying that both forms have exactly the same fields?

Comment: @manishie , just the class but different fields .
If it's possible to trigger and send the information to two specific form and submit the form with delay.

Comment: sure, but do we need to send field data to the other form, or are you just trying to trigger a form submit on the other form, submitting whatever data has been manually entered?

Comment: @manishie , send the field data in the form (.#contactform1) to the (.#aweber) and trigger submit button to both.

Comment: You need to submit the form and not the button so `var frm = this;` will be `var frm = $('#contactForm1');`

Comment: @ICanHasKittenz , Previously when I tried with var frm = this; , it worked and the function submitted the form.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#aweber').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var frm = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {
            email: email
        },
        success: function (data) {alert('first form submitted');
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                frm.submit();
            } else {
                alert('The e-mail address entered is not valid.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could I put the function frm.submit(); when the function is success for the second form?

Comment: sorry i don't understand.

Comment: If you looked my original code in the top , the current one is working with one form..When it's success I use the function frm.submit(); to submit the form.
But just now I've tried to implement your code , it didn't pass and submit the code to the second form.
When I entered it manually then it goes through .

Comment: Any other suggestion?? 
I want both to work cause I tried yours and cannot go through.

Comment: The second form submit didn't go through , when I checked the database it's empty.

Comment: before the second ajax call, put in an alert and make sure that you are reaching that point of the code.  let me know...

Comment: or is there a live site i can see this on?

Comment: i don't understand what you're doing in that code.  you have a bunch of frm.submit() lines for the second form.  that will not work because frm points to the first form.  you're trying to resubmit the second form two more times after already submitting it once.  and you are submitting the first form after you click the first form.  i don't get that.  you should submit the form when you click a button.

Comment: the code that you have on that site is very different than the code you pasted in the question.

Comment: Oh, it's because I'm still editing the code when i gave you the link trying to find solutions.
I'm stuck.

Comment: can you please paste in your original code, and replace the success callback with my code, then i'll look at it.

Comment: the code i'm seeing is identical to how it was previously.  it's sitll not the same code as the question above.

Comment: That's weird , i view the page source.
The first one below the center is the 2nd form, followed by the 1st form then followed by the ajax.Which part is not the same
?

Comment: i see your script starting with $('#contactForm1').click(function (e), not $('.wf-button').click(function (e) as you have above.

Comment: Oh , i forget to changed that ! Changed already sir the Ajax function . I thought was the whole source code ><

Comment: The submit button for the ajax is under the video , the button is invisible cause of the missing css.

Comment: your code was completely mixed up!  use my updated answer as a starting point and see if you can get it working.  i just tried that code (by entering it into the js console) and it gets me a little closer to what you're trying to do

Comment: Actually the first form could go through cause of the action , just I'm facing why doesn't the second form go through.
First works only second :(.I kinda need help.

Comment: i've corrected your code.  the first form is failing using the ajax method so you'll have to figure out why.

Comment: The first one i used it like this : $('#contactForm1').click(function (e) .

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: that code you just pasted doesn't make any sense.  why would you click a form?  use the code i pasted in, in its entirety.  start from that and see what you can figure out.  sorry, going to bed now!

Answer (score 0):

submit form if success always reload page.
Using ajax post to server.

You can try it:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).then( myFunc, myFailure );
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/